# jvectormap: Getting rid of black flicker on touch

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, jvectormap

I am using http://jvectormap.com/ for an iOS-app working with a webview internally. The problem I have is that there is black flickering when I touch a country on the world map.

You can even reproduce the problem with Safari on an iPad or iPhone when tapping on the demo map on the homepage of http://jvectormap.com/.

Does anybody know that problem? How can we get rid of this? It's a show stopper for my app.

Thanks a lot!

Kim

Edit: I added CSS -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; to * and the div-container which is containing the map -> does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It's the tap highlighting darkening. I cleared it with CSS

```
* {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Now I want to get rid of the empty space that appears when dragging...